# Finding a specific colour within a bitmap range - VB.net 2022

Tags: vb.net, colors, bitmap, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently trying to find the colour red within a bitmap range for a program that isn't VB.
The program will click once if the colour has been found, and if it hasn't been found will check for the colour again in a set period of time, say 200 milliseconds.

I'm utterly clueless on how to work with bitmaps and how to see if they detect a specific colour.
I've already got the area of the screen I want it to check but I'm unsure on how to check if red is within that area.

[ImageBounds] is just a placeholder btw.

[Here's what my code looks like right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8KOL.png)

I presume I'll need the colour checking area in its own function so it can be called again, other than this I have no clue what to do.